# Does pthreads in PHP work exactly the same as multi-threading in C does?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I'm a bit confused about pthreads in PHP. Everyone seem to suggest implementing multi-threading using pthreads.

Does this mean that the API exposed in PHP, named pthreads, is the same API exposed in C, named pthreads, or are Posix Threads and pthreads for PHP different things ?

Comment: Have you read the docs?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Comment: I think this is a valid question, there is not enough space to answer it here, if it is re-opened I will answer it ...

Comment: This is real multi-threading as mentioned by Joe. A web applicaiton server has been built based on this in PHP [**AppServer**](http://www.appserver.io)

Answer (score 4):

Programming with Posix Threads in PHP would be an awful mess, the very thing that makes it feasible at all is the fact that it is based around objects, for which Zend exposes many useful handlers, enabling the infrastructure for user threading to exists alongside Zend.

pthreads is a high level, object oreintated API (with windows support) for threading userland PHP scripts. It leverages parts of PHP that have existed for more than a decade, that are well tested and as well maintained as any other part of PHP is today.

For coming up to 14 years, PHP has been able to execute in multi-threaded environments, that's how mod_php works with the worker mpm, apache2 on windows, and some IIS setups too. pthreads leverages that same functionality, and Zend's Objects API to allow the user to write managed, multi-threaded code.

Further Reading: https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782